# Webpack Breaks Mocha in Node.js App

Tags: node.js, webpack, mocha.js, expect.js

I have a node.js app that uses Mocha and Expect for testing. All the tests work great, until I installed webpack for react. Now when I run "npm test" I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'should'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Brian\version-control\tysons-tech-map-redone\node_modules\watchpack\test\DirectoryWatcher.test.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\Brian\version-control\tysons-tech-map-redone\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:230:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\Brian\version-control\tysons-tech-map-redone\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:227:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\Brian\version-control\tysons-tech-map-redone\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:495:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Brian\version-control\tysons-tech-map-redone\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:469:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Below is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cool-map",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test || SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" && mocha **/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm test\""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.2.2"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.9",
    "validator": "^5.6.0",
    "hbs": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
    "supertest": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if webpack.config is necessary to post, but just in case:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        alias: {
            AdminUserTable: 'app/components/AdminUserTable.jsx'
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Running the command npm test works great when I uninstall webpack, I'm not sure why It's breaking mocha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `package.json` is missing `should` as a dependency.

Install it via;

`npm install --save-dev should`

Also I would recommend you look into [chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) which in my opinion provides a slightly different API.

Comment: Success! Thanks. I installed this and rimraf and it now worked. Can you shed any light on why adding webpack makes those two necessary?

Answer (score 1):

**should is an expressive, readable, framework-agnostic assertion library. The main goals of this library are to be expressive and to be helpful. It keeps your test code clean, and your error messages helpful.
By default (when you require('should')) should extends the Object.prototype with a single non-enumerable getter that allows you to express how that object should behave. It also returns itself when required with require.
It is also possible to use should.js without getter (it will not even try to extend Object.prototype), just require('should/as-function'). Or if you already use version that auto add getter, you can call .noConflict function.
Results of (something).should getter and should(something) in most situations are the same**

Better u install node dependency should with npm as below

```
npm install --save should
```

[should-reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should)